# stroke not showing up while drawing

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm in blender 3.4.1 grease pencil. When I draw a stroke, it is invisible until I release the mouse. thus, I cannot draw very accurately. Does anyone know how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: Working on a mac, by any chance? It's under investigation by Grease pencil developers, you can follow or subscribe to [the bug report here](https://developer.blender.org/T102251). For Mac, there will be Metal support in Blender release 3.5, which solves the problem.